# Ubuntu 18.04 voice announcements

Tags: orca

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04, and there is now an annoying voice that announces everything that I click on. How to get rid of this voice? Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

You may have clicked the screen reader 'ON' accidently. You can turn it off by going into Settings-->Universal Access-->Screen Reader-->Off. Hope it helps, if not, i can attach an screenshot.